# Approximation of triply periodic minimal surfaces with trigonometric level sets

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces, periodic-functions

Some [triply periodic minimal surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triply_periodic_minimal_surface) are known to be approximated by trigonometric level sets *very accurately*.

To see this, let's sample a gyroid scaled to the bounding box $[0, 1]^3$ *exactly* through its [Weierstrass-Enneper parametrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass-Enneper_parameterization). We can examine the distance to the nearest point on the level set

$$\cos(2\pi x)\sin(2\pi y) - \cos(2\pi y)\sin(2\pi z) + \cos(2\pi z)\sin(2\pi x) = 0:$$

[image]

The median relative error is ~$0.0004$ and max relative error is ~$0.0013$, and so this is a *very good* approximation for most applications.

A list of level sets that approximate other TPMS can be found [here](https://xyzdims.com/2023/02/).

### Question

How were these approximations derived or discovered? Perhaps through a series approximation to the Weierstrass-Enneper parametrization?

Are there ways to find more accurate approximations?

---

### Edit

I found the following excerpt [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140221023159/https://secure.msri.org/about/sgp/david/papers/nature96/index.html).

> These functions are not found by chance; they come from choosing an appropriate lowest-order term from the Fourier series of an electrostatic potential function derived from charges whose distribution has the desired space-group symmetry, or from a symmetrization procedure using generators of the space group. But there is as yet no real explanation as to why the match is so good in some cases and not at all accurate in others.

It’s not clear to me what this means exactly, and unfortunately there is no source listed.